# is Convert.toInt32(boolean) the only way in c# to do this?

Tags: c#, refactoring, boolean, dynamics-crm-2011

I have some code in c# which needs to increment a number by 1 if a certain boolean value is true, but else it needs to say the same. The only method i've found using the Immediate window in VS 2012 is by `+ Convert.ToInt32(boolean)`.

Am I missing something obvious in here somewhere? I thought since a boolean is basically true (1) or false(0) (let's forget about FileNotFound), it would be easier to coerce a boolean to an Int value.

edit:
false is 0, not 1

edit2: my original edit got swallowed up. I'm currently doing a nullcheck on the number (the number is a nullable int field from a Dynamics CRM 2011 entity). Is it possible to keep that nullcheck?

Comment: Don't make the mistake to assume what is the integer representation of true. Just false could be assumed to be zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that adding boolean flag to some value is very readable solution. Basically you want to *increment* (i.e. add 1) value if flag is `true`. So, simple if check will clearly describe your intent add do the job:

```
if (flag) value++;
```

UPDATE: According to your edit, you want to do two things:

1. Set default value to your nullable value
2. Increment value if some condition is true.

To make your code clear, I would not try to put both things in one line. Make your intent explicit:

```
value = value ?? 0; // 1

if (flag) // 2
    value++;
```

Comment: i'm doing a nullcheck as well, which I could do in the above way. Is there a way to keep this a oneliner while keeping the nullcheck for Value?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs `value` is a nullable number?

Comment: yes. value is a nullable int field from a  Dynamics CRM 2011 entity.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs and if `value` is null you want to assign `0` to it before incrementing?

Comment: yes, basically, because if the boolean is false, I STILL want to nullcheck it first. the nullcheck needs to happen whether the boolean is true or false.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs you can use one-liner with nullable check `value = (value ?? 0) + (flag ? 1 : 0)`, but that will make your code less readable

Answer (score 3):

The simple solution would be like so:

```
val += flag ? 1 : 0;
```

The fact is that a .NET boolean is simply a completely different type from integer (unlike in, say, C++, where it's a "renamed" integer). The fact, that it is actually implemented using an integer value, is implementation detail and not to be relied upon. In fact, you can do a lot of strange things when you mess with the actual value of the boolean (for example, using direct memory manipulation or overlapping structure fields) - the consistency goes away.

So, don't work with the "actual value of boolean". Simply expect the two possible values, `true` and `false`, and work with those.

Comment: what I'm currently doing is Object.Variable = (object.variable ?? 0) + Convert.ToInt32(boolean); Is there a way to add that nullcheck in here somewhere?

Comment: Of course, just use `Object.Variable = (Object.Variable ?? 0) + (boolean ? 1 : 0);`

Comment: (`a += b` is just a shortcut for `a = a + b`)

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the `null`-check and add the value according to the boolean, like this:

```
obj.Variable = (obj.Variable ?? 0) + (yourBoolean ? 1 : 0);
//obj is the instance of your object
//Variable is the nullable integer
//yourBoolean is the bool to check against
```

Answer (score 0):

Object.variable is int variable OR Nullable? If  Int varable it's default value is 0, and you can just write like this: `Object.variable+=bool?1:0`, else can use it: `Object.variable=Object.variable??0+bool?1:0`